# Django - add a function to an admin form under a particular field

Tags: python, django

I've made a function that iIwant to be able to run on the fly in my admin form, also that it would be reusable for multiple fields.

Basically, we have a dmvpn ip and a subnet. I would like to be able to click, find free ip/subnet then run my function against the current values other records have for the field

so findfreeip would sit next to both fields and find me the next available dmvpn IP in the 4th octet and it would find me the next available subnet in the 3rd octet. then maybe a pop showing the free ips/subnet and on click it would populate the field for me

[image: Admin form option]

Heres the model and the function

models.py

```
class ShowroomConfigData(models.Model):
    location = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    dmvpn_dsl_ip = models.GenericIPAddressField(protocol='IPv4')
    subnet = models.GenericIPAddressField(protocol='IPv4')
    ...
```

functions.py

```
def FindFreeIP(list_of_ips, octect): 
    #get the required octect from all IPs and put them in a list
    octect_list = []
    for item in list_of_ips:
     octect_list.append(getXOctect(item,octect))
    octect_list = sorted(octect_list)
    #go through the list and find the smallest free no
    usable = [] 
    for i in range(1,254):
        if i not in octect_list: 
            usable.append(i) 
    return min(usable)
```

I get all the subnets in a list and then send that list to the function which will then look for the next usable IP in the octect that you ask for

Answer (score 0):

in admin.py

```
from myproject.functions import FindFreeIP

class MyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    actions = [FindFreeIP]
```

Full details can be found on the django documentation site under [admin writing actions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/admin/actions/#writing-actions)

Comment: Please provide an explanation with your code, so the OP can learn from it.

Answer (score 0):

The right way to do it is to create your custom Widget and pass it to change form in admin.

Your widget could call a certain view via ajax to perform the IP lookup and fill the input with response.

Have a look at the django's source code for the [example](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/widgets.py#L79).